# How to invoke a hook from React class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Question from React newbie!
I have Material UI React login form and am trying to use hook within login form. But getting invalid hook call error. No luck so far. Help please.. loginformstyles.js is the hook I am trying to use in the signin.js file.. The login page has two text fields - username and password and a Submit button.

```
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { ValidatorForm, TextValidator} from 'react-material-ui-form-validator';
import { useStyles } from './loginformstyles';

export default class MyForm extends React.Component {

Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Task Manager
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

handleChange (event) {
  const email = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ email });
}


render() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
      <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} >
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            validators={['required', 'isEmail']}
            errorMessages={['this field is required', 'email is not valid']}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <this.Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
      width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
      margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
  }));
```

Comment: You can't use Hooks inside class components. You'll either need to refactor your class to be functional or wrap your component with an HOC. This link might be helpful in the latter: https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/how-to-use-react-hooks-in-class-components

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make this work, you could wrap the it and then expose the styles into child component, ex.

```
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return children(classes)
  }
```

and then you can do

```
  <Wrapper> 
    {classes => <Copyright classes={classes} />}
  </Wrapper>
```

Of course,  this is just to get it working. In general you shouldn't mix class and hook, but as long as you can turn them into components, then you can mix and match.

Comment: Thanks. yes, I know but I just want to get this working...  just want to know where to specify the code <Wrapper> For example, In the signin.js render method, <div className={classes.paper}> ... which is a hook prop... how do I change it using <Wrapper> tag

Comment: If `Copyright` is your component, you need to add a prop `classes` to it so that `<Wrapper />` replaces your `<Copyright />`. The reason is that `Wrapper` wrap your style inside.

Comment: @windmaomao it looks like his component is MyForm, Copyright is just a method that was capitalized.